# Dotted line in pdf file with IE 10

Tags: pdf, svg, internet-explorer-10, pdfmake, canvg

The graph is the same and correct on browser, Chorme, IE11, IE10, etc....

In IE 11, I press a button to create png file, the result is correct.

In IE 10, I press a button to create png file, the result is incorrect, the dotted line of graph change to solid line.

I have no idea about this problem, can anyone help me?

IE 11:[image]
<sub>(source: [2.pik.vn](http://2.pik.vn/20168ec36491-f539-4a6e-839e-f519455c3c49.png))</sub>

IE 10: [image]
<sub>(source: [2.pik.vn](http://2.pik.vn/2016b5296b4d-f7f0-4629-8132-695de8ad20df.png))</sub>

This is the code i use to convert from svg to canvas:

```
var svg = document.getElementById("graphP").innerHTML;   
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvg(canvas, svg);
var imgDataP = canvas.toDataURL();
```

Comment: How are you creating the PDF file?

Comment: Please share the pdf for analysis and reproduction of the issue.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I convert svg to canvas

Comment: Your answers are confusing. Your question talks about a PDF. But now you say you are converting an svg to canvas. Which is it?  If you are using a PDF, explain how you are creating the PDF. Also please provide a link to the PDF so we can examine it for errors.  How are you viewing it in IE10? IE doesn't come with a built-in PDF viewer like FF and Chrome do.

Comment: You may need to rewrite your question to be more clear on what exactly you are doing.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Sorry, I'll do better next time. This is my answer:
On the browser chorme, IE 11, IE 10, etc..., the result is the same and correct, look like the first picture in my post.
But when I create pdf file, the result is different. I use "canvg" method to convert from svg to canvas, then use canvas.toDataURL('image/png')  and use the pdfMake to create pdf file with that data. I added some code.

Comment: Have you checked whether the PNG generated with `canvas.toDataURL('image/png') ` looks correct or not?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau It is incorrect.

Comment: Then it must be a bug in IE. There is probably no easy way to fix it.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Yeah, It takes 5 day from me. But fortunately, customer are not required to fix this anymore. Thanks for your helping.