# Dotted line change to solid line when i create pdf file

Tags: internet-explorer, canvas, svg

I try to create a pdf file contains a graph with dotted line. It's working fine on Chorme, IE11. When I use IE10, the result on the browser is the same with IE 11, but when the pdf file was created, the dotted line change to solid line. I have no idea about this problem, can anyone help me?
I use this code to convert svg to canvas:

```
var svg = document.getElementById("graphP").innerHTML;   
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvg(canvas, svg);
var imgDataP = canvas.toDataURL();
```

And this is result:
IE 11: [image]

IE 10: [image]

Notice: The result is the same on browser, just diffirent when create pdf file.

Comment: You already posted this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40230693/dotted-line-in-pdf-file-with-ie-10).  If you want help, answer the questions we have asked you there. Don't post the same question again.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I added some code, maybe I don't understand ur question?
Pls tell me what do you want to know.